# Weird logging behavior in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Im new to typescript, so maybe this is normal for some reason.

I have a function that looks like this.

```
const testFunction = (arg1: string) => {
  let testInt = parseInt(arg1);

  console.log('testInt', testInt);

  console.log('arg1', arg1);
}
```

Output:

arg1 80%

No log for testInt

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: That code works fine. Make sure, if you're using your browser console, that the message is not being filtered.

Comment: OMG! Well done sir! Thanks, I thought I was losing my mind

Comment: Was it the console filter? That thing drives me nuts sometimes.

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes it was!